# Sending email to an MX record through an ASP.NET website using the SmtpClient class

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, mx-record

I've recently been having issues sending email from my web application. I keep getting a connection refused exception from the mail relay (and it's always the same mail relay). After some thorough discussion with the mail team, I've been told that I'm not using the MX record to sent the mail. However, I think I am. The MX-record is **mailhub-us.xxx.us.net**. Here is the code that I use to send emails (clearly I reference the mailhub address as the server)

```
    MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage();
    ****Some code to populate msgMail
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mailhub-us.xxx.us.net");
    smtpClient.Send(msgMail);
```

Yes, I'm aware I'd be better off using `<mailsettings>` in the web.config (something that I learnt during my research and something I intend to correct). I've checked to ensure that the MX records are set up at the DNS using nslookup and there are 3 servers configured for this entry.

I'm a little confused at this point, because I thought I was using the MX record and hence the failovers should automatically take place. Am I being stupid in saying that or is there something else that I'm missing? Any help in this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an exception for a refused connection or for a host not found? These are very different errors. Connection refused means that the mx record was used, server was found, but the server actively denied the mail request. That means it has nothing to do with the mx record. If it IS the mx record, your exception should indicate that it could not find the mail server.

Comment: that means it's not even remotely connected to the MX record. The mail team needs to re-evaluate the active refusal from a load perspective. The server wasn't too loaded down with traffic, it CHOSE to active refuse the connection. It could mean you've passed bad credentials somehow. If there is failover, a redundant server may be misconfigured. If the load is what they say it is, it could be the domain controller rejecting good credentials because of time-outs.

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.config` file add this

```
 <system.net> 
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="fromemail">
    <network host="hostname" defaultCredentials="false"
    port="xx" userName="xxxx" password="xxx" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

and in your backend code, you could do something like

```
       var message = new MailMessage();
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.From = new MailAddress(from);
        message.To.Add(to);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = msg;
        var client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Send(message);
```

Comment: Yes, I intend to make this change, however, this is the similar to what I currently have. I'm having issues with referencing the MX record that has been configured.

Comment: The above code does not work. It returns an error on ´´´message.From = new MailAddress(from);´´´ and says: *The name 'from' does not exist in the current context*

Comment: @Dieter: yes, because the `from` is not declared. you need to declare it and assign a value